# MongoDB aggregate lookup for items not listed in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using the following for population but not sure how to use the **negation** of population.

```
db.getCollection("storeCheckRecords").aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      store_ids: { $addToSet: "$store_id" },
    },
  },
  //   {
  //     $lookup: {
  //       from: "allStores",
  //       localField: "store_ids", // I want to do NOT IN store_ids
  //       foreignField: "_id",
  //     },
  //   },
]);
```

The above pipeline is rather simple, we get all the unique `$store_ids` first and then we want to list all the stores from the collection `allStores` such that it is **NOT** present in the array of `$stores`.

**My Attempt:** I know how to populate with the stores present in the field `store_ids` but I've no clue sure how to obtain the **negation**!

Look forward to your helpful comments! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result using below syntax of [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) and can use `$not` `$in` inside it.

```
db.getCollection("storeCheckRecords").aggregate([
  { "$lookup":  {
    "from": "allStores",
    "let": { "store_ids": "$store_ids" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$not": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$store_ids" ] }}}},
    ],
    "as": "allStores"
  }}
])
```